# Interpreting regression model output

Tags: regression, least-squares, interaction, interpretation, splines

I have a question on interpreting coefficients in a regression model. To be specific, the regression model is as given below:

$$y=a+b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3Z+b_4Zx_1+b_5Zx_2$$

where

```
  y= continuous dependent variable
  x1= independent variable all values are positive (min=0)
  x2= independent variable all values are negative (max=0)
  Z = Normalized variable with values between (0,1)
```

Given this set up, how would we interpret

```
  a) positive and significant coefficient b1
  b) negative and significant coefficient b4
  c) What can we say about a joint test of b1+b4=0
```

x1 and x2 represent the same variable X (continous) and the goal is to allow for different slopes when X is positive and negative. Any help is much appreciated.

The question is motivated from the regression output in the following paper

Greve, Henrich R. "A behavioral theory of R&D expenditures and innovations: Evidence from shipbuilding." Academy of management journal 46.6 (2003): 685-702.

Comment: welcome to CV! if it is a homework please show your attempt and add self-study tag

Comment: Hi. Actually no its not homework. I'm trying to understand the regression output from a published paper.

Comment: @Anup it would be very helpful if you could edit your post to add a full citation for the paper so others could look

Comment: @ssdecontrol: I have added the reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Answering these in turn:

1. This means:

   - when $Z = 0$, for every unit increase in $X_1$ above 0, $Y$ increases by $b_1$. So when $Z = 0$ and $X = 3$, if $b_1 = 2$ and $a = -1$, then $Y = 5$. If $X = 5$, then $Y = 9$.
   - we have sufficient evidence to reject the hypothesis that $b_1 = 0$, in favor of the hypothesis that $b_1 \neq 0$
2. This means:

   - for every unit increase in $Z$, the effect of $X$ on $Y$, when $X > 0$, increases by $b_4$. From above, if $Z=0$, $X=3$, $b_1 = 2$, and $a = -1$, then $Y=5$. But if $Z=2$ and $b_4 = 0.5$, then $Y = 8$. So the effect of $X$ is "amplified" by the value of $b_4$. In particular, $Y$ can be expressed as a function of $X$ in the form $Y = (b_1 + b_4 Z) X$ when $X > 0$.
   - we have sufficient evidence to reject the hypothesis that $b_4 = 0$, in favor of the hypothesis that $b_4 \neq 0$
3. A "joint test of $b_1 + b_4 = 0$" is the same as "a joint test of $b_1 = -b_4$". If we fail to reject this hypothesis, then every unit increase in $Z$ would offset $b_1$ by exactly 1, so an increase in $Z$ of 3 would reduce the effect of $X$ by 3. So our expression for $Y$ as a function of $X$ reduces to $Y = b_1 (1 - Z) X$.